# Can I have an array of integers for one constructor and a single integer for the other constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor

Are the following constructors allowed in the same `IntList` class?

```
IntList(int length);
IntList(int data[]);
```

Comment: I would if I could figure it all out. Still a bit new to C++. :) How would the call to initialize the `IntList(int data[])` look?

Comment: You don't need to call it - if these were the same types (i.e. you couldn't make a seperate overload for both), the definition alone would trigger an error. But for the record: `int xs[1] = {0}; IntList(xs);`

Comment: @delnan, When I do my `getLength()` method on an object with only one item in that array (similar to your example), it puts back `2`. I printed some information and found that it thinks that `sizeof(data)` is `8` when `sizeof(data[0])` is 4. Data is the name in the method that xs is passed as. However when I print the same information using `xs` instead of data (before the function call) it prints as expected.

Comment: @Tyler: That's a different (and nasty) question, but long story short: `int data[]` is `int *data` - arrays are not pointers, but abritary-sized array arguments are pointers. Ans since many 64 bit systems keep `int` at 32 bit (pointers are 64 bit - they must be because you lose one of the main advantages, larger address space, if they aren't).

Comment: @Tyler Crompton: C++ has its quirks inherited from C, and you have just hit one of them. In a function signature, `int data[]` is translated by the compiler into `int *data` (and I recommend that you do it yourself so what you read and what the compiler interprets are the same). At the place of call a similar process is performed, given an array `int array[5];` a call `IntList( array )` will *decay* the array into a pointer to the first element (equivalent to `IntList( &array[0] )`) and the size is lost. Google/search SO for "array decay" in C/C++ to get more info.

Comment: @delnan: Not only arbitrary sized array arguments, when the function signature is processed the type *array of N elements of type T* (with given size `[N]` or unbound size `[]`) are converted to *pointer to T*.

Comment: @David: Thanks for the extensive explanation, I wasn't sure how fixed-size arrays are handled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's fine, but note that latter is the same as `int* data`, which is a pointer and not an array.

Arrays are non-copyable and must be passed by reference:

```
typedef int array_type[5];

IntList(const array_type& arr); // same as: IntList(const int (&arr)[5]);
```

You can also take an array of any size using templates:

```
template <std::size_t N>
IntList(const int (&arr)[N]); // N is the number of elements
```

But your approach is ultimately unorthodox. If you want to initialize with a range of data, use iterators:

```
template <typename InputIterator>
IntList(InputIterator begin, InputIterator end);
```

Now you can iterate from `begin` to `end`, which can be iterators from any kind of container, like arrays, `std::vector`'s, `std::map`'s and more.

But you should be using `std::vector<int>` instead of `IntList` anyway.

Comment: @I am making a container class. That's the whole purpose of `IntList`.

Comment: @Tyler; I understand that you're making it, I'm saying don't. Perhaps instead: is this homework/an excercise?

Comment: @Tyler: Then implement it but never use it in practice. :)

Comment: @GMan, What if I wanted to initialize with say `{1, 3, 36, 2, 143, 72}`?

Comment: @Tyler: You cannot directly in C++03, you can in C++0x with initializer lists. The closest you can get is to initialize an array with that, then pass iterators to the start and end of that array.

Comment: @MarkB: I didn't mean for you to delete your answer, I was being flippant. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they're different types so this is valid.

Answer (score 0):

```
IntList(int length);
IntList(int data[]);
```

How ever, this not allowed to have as another method.

```
IntList(int* data);  // Error: This is equivalent to IntList(int data[])
                     // Because an array decays to a pointer.
```

Both the arguments are different. `length` is of type `int` and `data` is of type `int[]`, and is an example of constructor *overloading*.

---

Upon your comment as to how use it - This should serve as an example

```
class IntList
{
    int member[5] ;  // Added
    public:
       IntList(int length) ;
       IntList( int data[] )  // Should make sure that the passed array size is 5
                              // or take another argument mentioning the size of
                              // array being passed.
       {
           for(int i=0; i<5; ++i)
               member[i] = data[i] ;
       }
} ;


int a[] = { 1,2,3,4,5 };   // Making sure that array size is 5
IntList obj(a) ; // Array decays to a pointer pointing to first index of the array
```